# StormCrawler: urlfrontier.StatusUpdaterBolt performance bottleneck

Tags: stormcrawler

we are running a basic StormCrawler topology, which which we want to opt for high throughput.

Topology:

- FrontierSpout
- Fetcher
- JSoupParser
- DummyIndexer
- WarcBolt
- urlfrontier.StatusUpdaterBolt

However, after running the topology for a small amount of time, the cache of StatusUpdaterBolt seem to run full and the tuples fail ([Screenshot from Storm UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2UUK.png)).

The situation looks as follows in the Grafana dashboard of the URLFrontier (two Screenshots from Grafana dashboard; [first shortly after start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhjhO.png) and [second after a few minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZPmd.png))

This fail happens especially early, when the URLFrontier is running on a remote server and not locally besides the crawler. However, for our use case of the StormCrawler it is a crucial point that the crawlers run on different servers, which might even be separated by a high geographic distance, and nevertheless they share one Frontier. How is it possible to achieve high throughput and crawling speed in this distributed setup, without the StatusUpdaterBolt running full?

What we have tried so far, is the following: We modified the crawling pipeline, such that DISCOVERED urls are written into a log file, which is lateron uploaded to the Frontier, whereas the remaining urls are uploaded to the URLFrontier in the normal way (PutURLs command).

Is there another way to address this issue and overcome the bottleneck?
Something like:

- how to configure the urlfrontier.StatusUpdaterBolt properly, to prevent that the cache runs full?
- change the implementation of the waitAck cache in the StatusUpdaterBolt?
- or even waive the waitAck cache completely? This would mean that all tuples are acked and no tuples fail, so the communication between crawler and Frontier would follow the principle "Fire & Forget". What consequences would that have and would it be a meaningful tradeoff for crawling speed?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: let's start with the basics first.
which version of URLFrontier and StormCrawler are you running? which implementation of the Frontier are you running?
anything in the logs of URLFrontier or Storm's? I am not sure that the problem is that it runs full as the bolt  doesn't seem to be at capacity (0.38)
The tuples have been explicitly failed which can be due to either a timeout: no confirmation has been obtained for them OR the frontier returned an indication of failure.

Comment: @JulienNioche I use the latest StromCrawler version 2.9-SNAPSHOT. As frontier, I use the Opensearch implementation (to be precise, in the GitHub Repo: branch 2.x + some additional bugfixes because it didn't work out-of-the-box for me).
I also don't think it is the "bolt" which runs full, but it is the waitAck cache in the StatusUpdaterBolt. Due to the eviction policy of the waitAck cache, a tuple fails if the StatusUpdaterBolt hasn't received a confirmation with status OK from the frontier within the cache expiration time.

Comment: For the timeout, I didn't use any special configuration for the parameter `urlfrontier.cache.expireafter.sec`, so it should be 60 seconds by default. For the Storm topology timeout, I use the configuration parameter `topology.message.timeout.secs: 300`

Comment: https://github.com/PresearchOfficial/opensearch-frontier has not been updated for a while and might not be compatible with the urlfrontier module of SC. It is not part of the URLFrontier repo and is experimental. Are you able to run the same topo with URLFrontier running the default RocksDB based implementation and see if you are getting the same problem. Have you looked at the logs as I suggested previously?

Comment: @JulienNioche Thanks, I have provided the logs in the answer below, and tried to clearify it a bit. The original question was intended to be rather general. I'm okay with closing the question, but - having described our current situation - any feedback on how the pipeline with SC + URLFrontier could be made more performant, is welcome

Comment: we ran a large scale crawl with URLFrontier separated from the crawling instances although they were physically close and did not experience any issues. I don't think it would be a good idea to get rid of the wait ack cache mechanism for several reasons, one of them being that you would end up sending far too much data to the frontier without any way of throttling. It looks like in your current setup it is already struggling to keep up, you would make things even worse. Another aspect of course is that in some scenarios you don't want to lose any URLs ever.

Answer (score 0):

1st test: Running the described setup with URLFrontier (default RocksDB implementation)
In this case, the Frontier becomes irresponsive and the StormCrawler slows down, as it doesn't receive any new URLs from the Spout. The crawler is configured with `parallelism: 10` for the Spout, which presumably puts a too high workload on the URLFrontier.
Here are the corresponding logs:

```
11:50:52.413 [grpc-default-executor-2] INFO  c.u.service.AbstractFrontierService - Sent 31 from 25 queue(s) in 80647 msec; tried 1005705 queues. 6c57df91-69e2-4fb7-af81-7a1e$
11:50:52.443 [grpc-default-executor-2] INFO  c.u.service.AbstractFrontierService - Received request to get fetchable URLs [max queues 25, max URLs 10, delay 30] 1c6449d8-76e$
11:50:57.533 [grpc-default-executor-12] INFO  c.u.service.AbstractFrontierService - Sent 26 from 25 queue(s) in 60115 msec; tried 1005705 queues. 3f916309-6f8a-4ec6-bac0-83d$
11:50:57.568 [grpc-default-executor-12] INFO  c.u.service.AbstractFrontierService - Received request to get fetchable URLs [max queues 25, max URLs 10, delay 30] 8f312ecf-36$
11:51:27.429 [grpc-default-executor-9] INFO  c.u.service.AbstractFrontierService - Sent 25 from 25 queue(s) in 79580 msec; tried 1002027 queues. a3628be2-4b32-4e68-a7e2-09c8$
```

2nd test: Running with URLFrontier (modified OpenSearch implementation)
Due to the modifications on the URLFrontier, the retrieval of URLs from the Frontier is not a bottleneck for the crawler anymore. You can see it, when looking at the following log entries from the Frontier:

```
11:59:40.058 [grpc-default-executor-5] INFO  c.p.urlfrontier.OpensearchService - Sent 34 URLs from 25 host(s) in 1 msec; tried 34 URLs. beedb9a6-5b73-46ef-bdaf-35fd8582ad72
11:59:40.617 [grpc-default-executor-5] INFO  c.p.urlfrontier.OpensearchService - Received request to get fetchable URLs [max queues 25, max URLs 10, delay 30] e8bbda41-7d85-$
11:59:40.618 [grpc-default-executor-5] INFO  c.p.urlfrontier.OpensearchService - Sent 30 URLs from 25 host(s) in 1 msec; tried 30 URLs. e8bbda41-7d85-49f9-b80d-477c51c088dd
11:59:40.662 [grpc-default-executor-5] INFO  c.p.urlfrontier.OpensearchService - Received request to get fetchable URLs [max queues 25, max URLs 10, delay 30] ff7426b2-6809-$
11:59:40.663 [grpc-default-executor-5] INFO  c.p.urlfrontier.OpensearchService - Sent 29 URLs from 25 host(s) in 1 msec; tried 29 URLs. ff7426b2-6809-4737-b373-7e0a9658f8d2
```

So, when aiming for a higher throughput in the interplay between StormCrawler and URLFrontier, the performance bottleneck has been the retrieval of URLs, so the `GetURLs`. Apparently in the setup, it seems that now the upload of URLs via the StatusUpdaterBolt and the `PutURLs` command has become the performance bottleneck.
So the crawler crash, which is depicted in the Screenshot of Storm UI from above, is unfortunately difficult to reproduce with the default implementation of URLFrontier.

In `worker.log` of SC, I have encounter many of the following log entries:

```
2023-06-23 09:58:53.478 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.pascoonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.478 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.lubbockonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.eastorangeonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://www.ciceroonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.losangelesonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.elkhartonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.carrolltononline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.elmonteonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.danburyonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.rockhillonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.haverhillonline.us from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
2023-06-23 09:58:53.479 c.d.s.u.StatusUpdaterBolt ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9 [WARN] Evicted https://jobs.hanoverparkonline.us/retail from waitAck with 1 values. [EXPIRED]
```

It seems that the waitAck cache is constantly full. This problem might be related to the URLFrontier, which is presumably not able to handle all the `PutURLs` and keep up with the crawling speed. So it is probably necessary to further improve the software of the URLFrontier. My original question targeted the following: Is it from the perspective of the StormCrawler necessary, to wait for the ACK confirmation of the frontier? Could this be omitted as a trade-off for a higher crawling speed?

Comment: Will have a closer look later, the day job is keeping me pretty busy.
Quick question: do all instances of the StatusUpdaterBolts run on the same worker? If so, they would share all the fields as they are threads on the same object.
About the performance of the gets, the logs show that 1005705 queues are being queried (which I thought had been fixed) that could be why things are slow

Comment: Keeping aside the perfs of the default implementation, which should not take so much time to read (probably because of the multithreaded reads that can't spot that the required amount of URLs has already been sent - thought that had been fixed), the issue you are having is that the frontier doesn't ack the writes or at least not fast enough, removing the ACK mechanism would not solve the problem and possibly make it worse. Have you considered profiling the Frontier to see what blocks or takes time?